# Sqldatasource connect Oracle database with parameters, code behind not working

Tags: c#, oracle, parameters, sqldatasource

I need set 3 parameters in SQLDatasource, binding source to the gridview.
If I remove the parameters, and directly choose datasource from design view, it shows data correctly.
I guess after pass parameters, Oracle has some special way to handle the SQL, but once the parameter passed, gridview got nothing to display. How can I fix this?

See the aspx code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$        ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT d.* FROM DECODATA D where (D.FAMILY like :family) AND (D.SERIES like :series) AND (D.MODEL like :model) ORDER BY D.FAMILY, D.SERIES, D.MODEL">  
         <SelectParameters>  
            <asp:Parameter Name="family" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="series" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="model" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>  
The front code is automatically created.
```

Code-behind: Search Button: Even I hard code the parameters like that, still not working
    (This parameters setting works in SQL Server I know)

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["family"].DefaultValue = "CLASSIC LOW";
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["series"].DefaultValue = "%";
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["model"].DefaultValue = "%";
            GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: That's so strange. I just deleted the gridview control and add a new one, it works. The code works good.

Answer (score 0):

ok, here is my answer...

```
 try
        {
            var oraCntStr = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource =
                    "<something to connect to your database>",
                UserID = "<login>",
                Password = "<password>"
            };

            using (OracleConnection oraCntgv = new OracleConnection(oraCntStr.ToString()))
            {
                oraCntgv.Open();
                OracleCommand oraCmd = oraCntgv.CreateCommand();
                oraCmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("<parameter's name>", OracleDbType.Varchar2));
                oraCmd.Parameters["<parameter's name>"].Value = Unum;
                oraCmd.CommandText = @"<Select sentence with your <:parameter's name>>";
                OracleDataReader oraReader = oraCmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (oraReader.HasRows)
                {
                    GridView1.DataSource = oraReader;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
                oraCmd.Dispose();
                oraReader.Close();
            }

        }
         catch (Exception err)
        {
            tbxTFStr.Text = "Something goes wrong: " + err.Message;
        }
```

it works for me... this solution uses ODT by Oracle, and don't forget to add

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
```

i used this solution in web-application